# How to start with protractor automation using jasmin

Tags: protractor

I am new to protractor. I started to automate a small application using protractor. My question is do we create the project  straight away using package.json  by mentioning dependencies  or
Do we install selenium , protractor through command prompt then write scripts. Once all done and working fine,  then build the project using package.json again?
Please some one clarify me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Protractor is used for end to end testing of another web project

You can create a separate folder called `e2e` in your project folder.
You can use the same `package.json` file, but create a new configuration file for e2e.

In the `npm` scripts you can first, build the project first and then run the test script.

Finally, I would say that a separate project is not required, as they are part of the same application.

I have worked on a couple of protractor projects. Feel free to ask anything.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: I am looking for a sample project in protractor jasmine to get basic understanding on how to organize scripts(like frame work) .Is it possible to share me a sample structure?

Comment: I can help you with that

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple project by downloading angular CLI project onto your workspace.

You can refer to any angular CLI site or video to start with. You will get all needed folders to start with, like e2e, src, etc and files like package.json, protractor conf etc.